# Insert in Ordered Linked List (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble creating an insert function for an ordered Linked List. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initial_data):
        self.data = initial_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        output_string = ''

        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            output_string += str(current.get_data())
            next_node = current.get_next()

            if next_node is not None:
                output_string += "->"

            current = next_node

        return output_string

    def insert(self, data):
        other = self.head
        previous = None
        if other is None:
            new_node = Node(data)
            new_node.set_next(self.head)
            self.head = new_node
        else:
                while data > other.get_data():
                    previous = other
                    other = other.get_next
                previous.set_next(Node(data))
```

Comment: This looks like a lot of work! I suggest using the built-in `list` type instead.

Comment: @Kevin: `list` is not a linked list, especially not for the purposes of a data structures class..

Comment: So where are you stuck? You implemented *something*, can you give us some sample inputs, expected output and what you get instead? If there are errors, please include those too (full traceback).

Comment: As an aside: there's no good reason to use getters and setters in Python. Just use the attribute, and if you find you need custom logic for getting or setting use a `@property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *insert* your item into the list. That means you need to:

- Break up the chain at the place you are going to insert
- Create a new node
- Join up the chain again with your new node in the middle.

You don't technically need to break up the chain, as setting the next link on the `previous` item will clear the old link, so all you need to do still is join up the chain again:

```
while data > other.get_data():
    previous = other
    other = other.get_next()
new = Node(data)
previous.set_next(new)
new.set_next(other)
```

I also corrected a different error, you didn't *call* `Node.get_next()`.

Next, you need to think more about edge cases. What happens when you get to the *end* of your chain but haven't found *any* node where `node.get_data()` is greater than your inserted data?

You need to adjust your `while` loop to make sure that you test for that case; `other` will be `None` for the last element of the chain:

```
while other is not None and data > other.get_data():
    previous = other
    other = other.get_next()
new = Node(data)
previous.set_next(new)
new.set_next(other)
```

There are other things you can do to improve your code. There is no need to use setters and getters in Python; there is no cost involved in turning attributes to `@property`s in the future, so just use attributes here.

You could also make your `Node()` accept a next element in the constructor, that'd make inserting an element easier.

You can use `str.join()` to insert a fixed string between elements of a sequence. Put all your `data` attributes into a Python `list` and join that list.

You do not need to set `self.head` as the next node when creating an initial element (when `self.head` is `None`); that's the default already anyway:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initial_data, next=None):
        self.data = initial_data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        data_list = []    
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            data_list.append(str(current.data))
            current = current.next
        return '->'.join(data_list)

    def insert(self, data):
        other = self.head
        previous = None
        if other is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
        else:
            while other is not None and data > other.data:
                previous = other
                other = other.next
            previous.next = Node(data, other)
```

Demo:

```
>>> ll = LinkedList()
>>> str(ll)
''
>>> ll.insert(10)
>>> str(ll)
'10'
>>> ll.insert(20)
>>> str(ll)
'10->20'
>>> ll.insert(15)
>>> str(ll)
'10->15->20'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this:

```
    else:
            while data > other.get_data():
                previous = other
                other = other.get_next
            previous.set_next(Node(data))
```

to this, should make it work.

```
    else:
            # First condition will short circuit so there won't be exception on calling other.get_data() if other is None
            while other is not None and data > other.get_data():
                previous = other
                other = other.get_next()
            node = Node(data)
            node.set_next = previous.get_next()
            previous.set_next(node)
```

Also, getter and setter methods aren't really necessary in python.
The convention is to use `@property` annotation if you need that kind of behavior and private members are usually prefixed with one `_`.